# Unknown server tag 'asp:EntityDataSource'

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-3.5

I uploaded my files to my remote server having support for ASP.Net 3.5. Website is developed using ASP.Net 3.5 and Entity Framework. Also i copied the dlls to bin folder. But i am getting the following error

arser Error Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Unknown server tag 'asp:EntityDataSource'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `compilation` section of your web.config, you need to add:

```
<compilation debug="true" defaultLanguage="C#">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
```

In the `controls` section, you need to add:

```
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
  </controls>
```